# Cannot connect to remote ipcluster - TimeoutError

Tags: ipython

I have ipcluster running on a remote linux server and I connect remotely from a MS Windows PC. The server is not visible from outside, so I need to connect using ssh tunnels through other machine that I defined in the json file. However, many attempts (and kernel restarts) are required to connect successfully, usually I get TimeoutError

```
rc=Client("ipcontroller_client.json", sshkey="key.txt")

C:\Local\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\parallel\client\client.py in __init__(self, url_or_file, profile, profile_dir, ipython_dir, context, debug, exec_key, sshserver, sshkey, password, paramiko, timeout, **extra_args)
    384         self._queue_handlers = {'execute_reply' : self._handle_execute_reply,
    385                                 'apply_reply' : self._handle_apply_reply}
--> 386         self._connect(sshserver, ssh_kwargs, timeout)
    387 
    388     def __del__(self):

C:\Local\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\parallel\client\client.py in _connect(self, sshserver, ssh_kwargs, timeout)
    488         evts = poller.poll(timeout*1000)
    489         if not evts:
--> 490             raise error.TimeoutError("Hub connection request timed out")
    491         idents,msg = self.session.recv(self._query_socket,mode=0)
    492         if self.debug:

TimeoutError: Hub connection request timed out
```

Also, once connected, after certain time of inactivity (~15 minutes) the connection seems to die and if I issue some command that needs to talk to the cluster (e.g., rc.queue_status()) the whole ipython session becomes unresponsive.

I did not find anything useful in the server logs, I can always see the initial connection established and closed, and in, case of success, opening additional connections as various ssh tunnels (?) are created.

Are there some specific settings (sshd_config) that need to be adjusted on linux ssh server? How can I keep the connection alive (or reconnect)?  Thank you.

Comment: You are probably the first user to try connecting to a cluster over an ssh tunnel from Windows, so there may well be a bug.  You should check for process, to see if the tunnels are active.  This could be a failure to build tunnels properly with paramiko.